# Drop zone directive for Angular CDK drag-drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular2-directives, angular-cdk

I am relatively new in Angular 2+ and I want to drag a div within another div. I am using [Drag & Drop CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) and wrote the following code to do that;

```
<div cdkDrop>    
    <div cdkDrag class="wrapper">
         <header cdkDragHandle class="widget__header">{{ title }}</header>
         <section class="widget__content">{{ content }}</section>
     </div>
</div>
```

I read in this [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290) that for having a drop zone, you just need to add cdkDrop directive to your div but it doesn't work for me although dragging is OK. Can anybody tell me how to define the drop zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found same problem with cdkDrop too and after google I found it rename to cdkDropList sine [v7.0.0-rc.2 (2018-10-15)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) so you can use it instead.